# Creating a regular expression in R statistics

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to create a regular expression in "R" to capture two groups of characters for me and I seem not to be able to figure out why it does not work.

Here is what I am trying to achieve ...

From this string:

```
"air.BattleofZombies                                   0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

I would like to return:

```
"air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

Instead, here is what I get:

```
"air.BattleofZombie=                                    0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027="
```

My regular expression query is:

```
gsub("([^\\s]*)[\\s]*([-?\\d*\\.?\\d*\\s*]*)","\\1=\\2", "air.BattleofZombies                   0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027")
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: I think the curly braces + text + spaces is misleading in your example.  Why not leave them out and let the multiple spaces stand for themselves?  I edited feel free to roll back if you feel this is unwarranted.

Answer (score 2):

I find character classes easier to use. (I think @Simon is wrong about what "\s" will match.)

```
> tst <- "air.BattleofZombies                   0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
> sub("[ ]{2,}", "=", tst)
[1] "air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"'
```

See the ?regex page and notice this sentence:  "Symbols \d, \s, \D and \S denote the digit and space classes and their negations." Nontheless, I have found that a literal space, `" "`, often works even without the character-class mechanism. (I'm unable to comment on a deleted post but I see now that this is the same answer posted earlier by @KaraWoo and the only reason it didn't deliver the desired result was that gsub was used.)

Comment: Thanks for the comment about `\s` - it matches a space outside a character class but not inside so I've changed my answer to clarify that point. This answer is simpler and easier to follow than mine, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

Another short solution:

```
vec <- "air.BattleofZombies                                   0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
sub("\\s+", "=", vec)
# [1] "air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems to solve, I think. First, `\\s` in a character class (i.e. inside `[]`) matches an `s` rather than a space unless one uses `perl=T` (so I've replaced it with just a space). Second, `gsub()` replaces multiple times so I've replaced it with `sub()`. Also, the character class in the second set of parentheses would be better as parentheses instead. The following regexp solves the problem:

```
sub("([^ ]*) +((-?\\d*\\.?\\d* *)*)","\\1=\\2", "air.BattleofZombies                   0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027",1)
[1] "air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I'd missed that character class when I copied the original line of code. It would be more appropriate as parentheses so I've edited my answer to make it parentheses. Thank you for noticing my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Just turn the starting `([^\\s]*)` to `([^\\s]+)` because the regex you used must catch empty strings also and remove all the `*`'s inside the character class, because `*` inside character class will looses his special meaning and matches only the literal `*`. So turn `[\\d*\\s*\\.]` to `[\\d\\s.]`

```
> gsub("([^\\s]+)\\s*([-\\d.\\d\\s]*)", "\\1=\\2", x, perl=T)
[1] "air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

**OR**

```
> gsub("(\\S+)\\s*((-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)(?:\\s+(?3))*)", "\\1=\\2", x, perl=T)
[1] "air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

`(?3)` recurses the pattern inside the third capturing group. Easy understandable form of this regex  was given below.

**OR**

```
> gsub("(\\S+)\\s+(-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s+-?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)*)", "\\1=\\2", x, perl=T)
[1] "air.BattleofZombies=0.0008  0.0006 -0.0027"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qA1rV2/1)

Comment: All good stuffs folks. I learned a lot with your answers. Very appreciated.